# is there more than one layer to constrain on a button in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uibutton, constraints

I'm attempting to remove a UIImageView from my viewController in a swift Xcode project, if a certain condition exists (if a user has purchased "remove ads"). I am able to do so by setting the images' `.image` to `nil` and the constraint that sets it's size to `nil`. however when I do this, the buttons go to the correct location at the bottom of the view, but the button's *pressable area* is no longer the entire button. I can press it if I touch the bottom left corner of it.

if I am able to present the appearance of the button in the proper place, how do I affect the *functional* area it?

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: @dfd what code would be most useful to you? the constraints are built using story board, thus I did not post them.

Comment: Upload before & after images may help people understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used, instead of just `nil` for the image and banner view.

```
        self.adBannerView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.bottomGreyArea.removeFromSuperview()

        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute:.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backButton, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide, attribute:.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

removing from the superview cleared out all the constraints, so I then rebuilt the relevant constraints for the buttons (which previously depended on the `bottomGreyArea`. all is well in the world again!

Answer (score 0):

You should check the button new `frame` or any view in front of the button that catch the touch event.

Normally, UIButton touch area is its frame area.